# web.config file not there in the root(/) directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor, webmatrix

I was trying to run a `.cshtml` file but it gave an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


This type of page is not served. 
  Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /index.cshtml
```

So I searched for the solution and found that I had to edit the `web.config` file which is in the root directory(here it is My Site), but there is no file like that there there is only an `index.cshtml` which I had created.

I searched even the `IIS` and the `IIS Express` folders in `Programs Files\` but there was no file like that?

Comment: @Adriano This is not an MVC site. It's a Web Pages site.

Comment: You can add a web.config file but you will probably need to choose the option to show all file types in the Add File dialog. Also, GmG provides some relevant guidance in his reply below about the template you should use in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebMatrix, maybe your mistake was the starting point choice.

If you want to create a new Web Pages site you must start from a template in the Template Gallery of WebMatrix. Pay attention that the Empty Site template differs from the Empty Site option outside the Template Gallery because the first holds the files (binaries, packages and the web.config too) that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

As the server error suggests, `.cshtml` files are not served, the reason for this is because they are server-side files that make up your application, they are just one piece of a much bigger picture.

If you launched your web application in debug mode and the URL in the browser was something like `http://localhost:2932/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, just drop the `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` part of the URL.

Comment: This would be true if the OP was developing an MVC site. But the use of WebMatrix suggests this is a Web Pages site.